# Сохранение положения sidebar при помощи local Storage

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Привет всем, нужна помощь по использованию локального хранилища.Нужно чтобы браузер запоминал действие пользователя при сворачивании/разворачивании sidebar.

Скрипт sidebar

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Весь код [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrXOxy)

Comment: Используйте куки, как вариант, но вы должны понимать, что если их удалят все вернется к изначальным настройкам, если у вас все пользователи будут авторизованы можно такие настройки хранить у него в профайле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```
var toggled = localStorage['toggled'] == 'true';
$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled", toggled);

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  toggled = !toggled;
  localStorage['toggled'] = toggled;
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

[Демо на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/qb7g3g6e/) т.к. SO не дает работать с `localStorage`.

Comment: Хороший пример, а можно ли сделать так чтобы sidebar был изначально спрятан до помещения ключа в локальное хранилище?

Comment: `var toggled = localStorage['toggled'] === undefined || localStorage['toggled'] == 'true';`